# Questions about Samsung Galaxy S security applications

Tags: applications, security, antivirus, firewall

Hello
I would like to know whether is it recommended to have some antiVirus+firewall application for this current phone? (I usually open email attachments for example)

1.Do these applications runs all the time in the background also when I'm not connected to WAP or WiFi?

2.In case you recommend to have such apps , which applications do you prefer?

3.Is it true that the more application I use I can mess up the whole android system like the registery in ordinary computers) and it can lead to the whole device to malfunction or to be more slow (like ordinary computer)?

4.According to question 3: What can I do to secure my system? Do I have some option to restore the whole android system if it will get massed up and bugy in the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> 1.Do these applications runs all the time in the background also when I'm
>   not connected to WAP or WiFi?

That depends on the specific security application.

> 2.In case you recommend to have such apps , which applications do you
>   prefer?

I prefer being cautious in what I install, rather than having Big Brother Watching Over Me. As a Linux-based system, Android have a very strong security base and the Android framework on top of of it is very paranoid about security. Android is -- for all practical purpose -- impermeable to worm-type virus. However, like any Unix system, Android does not protect you from you taking a gun and shooting your own foot. If you tell Android to trust an application, Android will trust the application; if you give trust to the wrong application, don't blame the system for it.

> 3.Is it true that the more application I use I can mess up the whole android
>   system like the registery in ordinary
>   computers) and it can lead to the
>   whole device to malfunction or to be
>   more slow (like ordinary computer)?

If you're installing many applications that starts background services, then yes, it can slow down the system. Applications that are not running does not affect the speed of the system.

> 4.According to question 3: What can I do to secure my system? Do I have some
>   option to restore the whole android
>   system if it will get massed up and
>   bugy in the future.

There is a bunch.

- There is a factory reset on `Settings > Privacy > Factory data reset`.
- If you buy the phone from your carrier, they usually can reflash your phone with original ROM.
- On rooted phones, you can make a Nandroid backup.
- On custom ROMs, you can make a ClockworkMod Recovery backup.
- On many phones you can download and flash 3rd party or leaked original ROMs by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In case of smartphones I would be more worried about the physical security than malware. It's essential to have an application that allows you to locate the phone or at least remotely wipe all the data in case of robbery (or when you simply forget it). I use [WaveSecure](https://www.wavesecure.com/) for that, but I'm sure there are other alternatives (feel free to add them in comments).

Comment: As the questioner mentions that they're on a Galaxy S, it's worth adding that this function is built into the Galaxy S in many regions (such as much of Europe and the Far East) as Mobile Tracker in Settings, Security and Location, and uses the http://www.samsungdive.com website to issue the remote locate, lock and wipe functions.

Comment: @Gathrawn: I didn't know that. I just created a Samsung acccount. But I assume you have to have the 'Mobile tracker' on for this feature to work, no ? Do you happen to know if this drains the battery much ?

Comment: @Edelc I don't think it drains the battery at all normally, I certainly haven't noticed. All it does is when you request your phone's location from SamsungDive your phone is sent this request through whichever data connection it has active at the time, your phone then activates GPS itself, sends some data back and forward, and then GPS switches back off and everything goes back to normal.